# Need help in dynamic soql Formation

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql, dynamic-apex

I have a requirement where in dynamic query i have to change the format of a string.Below is the way i have tried i am getting following error after adding `getTempStringFormatValue` method in the below query:

> expecting a right parentheses, found '('

```
queryString += ' AND (FirstName like :tmpsearchstring OR LastName like :tmpsearchstring OR Name like :tmpsearchstring OR EMail like :tmpsearchstring OR Phone like :getTempStringFormatValue(tmpsearchstring))';

  public static String getTempStringFormatValue(String s) {
    String phoneNumber;
    System.debug('Phone value'+s);
    if (s!=null) 
    { 
     phoneNumber = '('+s.substring(0,3)+')'+' '+s.substring(3,6)+'-'+s.substring(6,10);
     System.debug('format phone'+phoneNumber);
    }

    return phoneNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call a method inside a dynamic soql query.

You have to store the result in a variable before calling your query. Like this:

```
String tmpString = getTempStringFormatValue(tmpsearchstring);
queryString += ' AND (FirstName like :tmpsearchstring OR LastName like :tmpsearchstring OR Name like :tmpsearchstring OR EMail like :tmpsearchstring OR Phone like :tmpString)';
```